# Screen touch problem

Tags: recovery-mode

I recently had thought of downgrading my youtube app to lower version, as I did liked that version, therefore I did 'clear data' on youtube, which was completely silly, now my phone ASUS zenphone 3 max ZC520Tl got shut down recently and when I try to start it again I cant make a touch to draw my pattern lock or do anything, on screen which requires touch command to proceed.

After a bit of research I tried doing to 2 things to be specific.

1st: I did backup user data in recovery mode, and then I did root Integrity check to detect the problems. it found 9 files missing. in directory of `/system/app/t6/` followed by : `cfg.ini,iffa.ca, iffa-key-to-import`, and several other long extensions. Please provide proper guidance.

Comment: Clearing data of the YouTube app should have nothing to do with the touch screen. That's besides the fact that clearing data wouldn't revert the app to the earlier version. Try using an otg cable to access your phone

Comment: thanks tried that. it did worked. I did backup my data on drive. but was thinking to solve this problem without formatting, if possible?